# sql query ORA-01843

Tags: sql, database, oracle, ora-01843

I have the following `DDL` and `DML` statements :

```
create table emp_details (
ID number(2) constraint t_pk primary key,
F_Name varchar(10) not null,
L_Name varchar(10) not null,
DOB date,
Mob_no number(10),
City varchar(10),
PIN number(5),
Gender char(1),
Designation varchar(15),
Join_Date date,    
);

insert into emp_details values (01,'John','Wick','1990-07-05',9856482358,'Goa',403001,'M','SDE II', '2015-01-08');
```

then, I get the error of `ORA-01843`. So, what could be the problem?

Comment: Im getting error ORA-01843 not a valid month

Comment: I've tried inserting null but that doesnt work
Ive tried using to_date('19900705','yyyymmdd') but no help

Comment: Your dates are missing the `date` keyword. The second date was correct originally, but seems to have been edited so now you have two errors.

Comment: Also the `varchar` and `char` columns should be `varchar2` (the standard string type in Oracle).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do here is to use ANSI date literals instead of strings for the dates (using strings will depend on the value of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and you don't want to play around with that if you don't have to):

```
INSERT INTO emp_details
VALUES
  ( 01, 'John', 'Wick', DATE'1990-07-05', 9856482358
  , 'Goa', 403001, 'M', 'SDE II', DATE'2015-01-08');
```

I have to add that explicitly listing the columns into which you're inserting values is a good habit to have. Otherwise, your `INSERT` query will break if you or someone else adds a column from your table:

```
INSERT INTO emp_details
  ( id, f_name, l_name, dob, mob_no, city, pin, gender, designation, join_date )
VALUES
  ( 01, 'John', 'Wick', DATE'1990-07-05', 9856482358
  , 'Goa', 403001, 'M', 'SDE II', DATE'2015-01-08');
```

Last, another good practice is to use `VARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR` when you're working with Oracle. Currently they work the same, but Oracle "reserves the right" to change `VARCHAR` to meet with the ANSI standard under which `NULL` values and the empty string won't be the same (with `VARCHAR2` they will always be the same). IOW, the behavior of `VARCHAR` values in Oracle can change.

Comment: I copied your query and now I get ORA-01438:value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

Comment: The pin number is too big. You specified 5 digits of precision when you created the table - a six-digit number (`403001`) won't work. Sorry I didn't spot that before.

Comment: Please accept/upvote my answer if it's been helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems when you query with

```
select * from nls_session_parameters p where p.parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

you won't get `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY-DD-MM` from your result of error `ORA-01843`.

*This problem is due to inserting wrong-formatted value for date columns `DOB` and `Join_date`.*

There may be two ways to prevent this error :

- Assume you get `DD/MM/YYYY` from above query, then use `05-07-1990` for
  `DOB`, and `08/01/2015` for `Join_Date` columns, respectively.
- Format your values as `to_date('1990-07-05','YYYY-MM-DD')` for
  `DOB` and `to_date('2015-01-08','YYYY-MM-DD')` for `Join_Date`